# Solving $e^z=\pm1$ in $\bf C$

Tags: complex-numbers

given $e^z = -1$

we have: $e^z = 1*e^{i\pi}*e^{2ki\pi}$
and taking $ln$ both sides yields: $z = ln(1)+i\pi+2ki\pi$

and if given $e^z = 1$

we have : $e^z = 1*e^{2ki\pi}$ and taking $ln$ both sides yields: $z = ln(1)+2ki\pi$

**is this analogy correct?, thanks for any help that you can offer**

i referenced the following post but just need clearity on this (finals have me shook up)
[[Can someone please explain the following definition of $\ln(e^z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065893/can-someone-please-explain-the-following-definion-of-lnez][1])

and

[[solving for z in $|e^z| = 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995080/solving-for-z-in-ez-2][2])

Comment: The complex exponential is not injective. Indeed, it is $2\pi i$ periodic. Thus, $e^{z+2k\pi i}=e^z,\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}, z\in\mathbb{C}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^z$ and $-1$ are two complex numbers, which are equals iff their real and imaginary part are. Now
$$
e^z=e^xe^{iy}=e^x\cos y+ie^x\sin y
$$
This is equal to $-1$ iff $\sin y=0$ (i.e. $y=k\pi$) and $-1=e^x\cos k\pi=e^x(-1)^k$  so we take $x=0$ and odd $k$'s.

We finally conclude that $z=x+iy=(2k+1)\pi i$.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid logs.

Note that $e^z=\pm1$ iff $e^{2z}=1$ iff $2z = 2k\pi i$ iff $z=k\pi i$.